# Simple open-source file encryption tool

Tags: openssl, aes, file-encryption, zip

I want to securely encrypt files, with an open algorithm.

So, i've constructed the simple openSSL shell command. How secure is it?

```
function aes-enc() { openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -in $1 -out "$1.aes" }
# Now, encrypt zip archive.
aes-enc hello.zip
```

What could be improved here? How long should the passphrase be in order to make the brute force unfeasible?

Should I use something else instead of OpenSSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 years later, the answer seems to be:

1. Use `argon2id` or `scrypt` with high parameters and some salt to transform 12-word BIP39 mnemonic or 12+ character password into 32-byte `key`.
2. Use `xchacha20poly1305` to encrypt file contents. Use `key` from step 1 and generate new 24-byte `nonce` *every time* from CSPRNG, then prepend nonce to encrypted file contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a simple passphrase-based approach, then your encryption is at most as secure as your passphrase. And even if you are using a long passphrase, your encryption is at most as secure as the [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) used to get from the passphrase to the actual key. Openssl uses a simple [MD5 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) to generate the key, which has two drawbacks:

1. It limits your effective key length to 128 bits, so even with a long passphrase, there is not point in using AES-256 over AES-128.
2. Its security from collision attacks is [in doubt.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) Now whether this is a problem for a simple file encryption scheme i don't know.

The weakest link will be the passphrase itself though. How long does it have to be? Well the better question is: how much [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) does it need? This question can only be realistically answered if the passphrase is randomly created. Take as an example [diceware:](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) here each word in the passphrase has 12.9 bits of entropy, meaning that an attacker has to try all 7776 words in the diceware dictionary to decrypt the file (well, yes, statistically, the attacker will succeed after half that number). A five word diceware passphrase gives you about 64 bits, a ten word passphrase about 129 bits of entropy. This means that you need a ten word passphrase to have the MD5 hash of openssl cut entropy off, and shows how much weaker than the other links the passphrase usually is.

Comment: Previous versions of openssl used a very weak key derivation process to derive an encryption key from the password, as correctly stated in this answer. However, version 1.1.1 of openssl now supports key derivation using PBKDF2, with a randomly generated salt and multiple iterations (10,000 by default) of sha256 hashing.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31492/file-security-when-encrypting-files-directly-with-the-openssl-command-and-what/229597#229597 for more info.