# Encrypting individual files on OS X

Tags: encryption, cryptography, file-encryption, macos

I am about to go paperless, and I want to protect the documents that I scan. The use case is that I'll be scanning paper documents, encrypting each file, and storing them locally and on various backup destinations. I've been researching various ideas for how to protect those documents, but I need more guidance. Here are the details of the system I'm trying to implement:

- Protection is at file level. If someone gets their hands on a file, I want them to be unable to use it.
- Transmission safety is out-of-scope, and assumed to be handled by whatever system is transporting the file.
- The files will be encrypted on a Mac.
- Decryption should be as widely-available as possible. For example, if I want to view a file on my iPhone, I should be able to use an existing library to write an app to do so.

I've looked at using security and encryption libraries in OS X to make a lightweight tool for this. I'm a software engineer, so I'm perfectly comfortable with writing my own application, but I am new to security. I am not comfortable making the security decisions without consulting people who know more than I do.

- I've considered AES, but then I read about padding and encryption modes, and I got lost in the details of which to choose.
- I've considered GnuPG, but I don't like the idea of having to download a separate tool. Yes, it's open source, but if I can use functionality built into the OS, that would be preferred.

Is there a recommended approach for this?

Comment: "Decryption should be as widely available as possible" seems to conflict with an OS level tool. Maybe that's not an issue if you're exclusively in the OSX/iOS world, but even then you may have differences in version and inclusion, and if not now then next release cycle. http://www.tgdaily.com/software-features/62970-apple-ios-and-os-x-will-not-converge[link]

Comment: I'm baffled by what solution you're envisioning, such that writing your own tool is in-scope but downloading a widely-used OSS one isn't? Anyhow, GPG (and the general OpenPGP spec) has some serious design flaws, but it's still better than anything you're likely to roll yourself, it's adequately secure, it (or compatible software) runs on everything, and it isn't too hard to use or too easy to misuse. There are better file encryption tools but they aren't yet widespread.

Answer (score 3):

You can use openssl like this:

```
openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -salt -a -in /file/to/encrypt -out /file/encrypted
```

Replace -e with -d to decrypt. It should work both on OS X and Linux, don't know on other systems however.
    man openssl to list the options and the available cipher.

Edit: looks like openssl applies few rounds of MD5 (not the best hashing algorithm) to the key derivation. This makes brute force attacks easier.

A better solution could be GnuPG (i know you asked for a preinstalled tool by the way):

To encrypt:

```
gpg -c -a --cipher-algo AES256 /file/to/encrypt
```

To decrypt:

```
gpg /file/to/decrypt
```

Comment: This may not be a great solution. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31492/file-security-when-encrypting-files-directly-with-the-openssl-command-and-what

Comment: Matteo, I think if you add a few comments about the limitations of this solution, it will be a good answer.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I think you are referring to Halen's comment, he posted the security implications.

Comment: I am, but you can incorporate the info into your answer. What you wrote isn't really wrong, it just has limitations.

Comment: I'm warming up to the idea of using gpg. I read that using the same encryption key for multiple pieces of data is insecure. Is this something I should worry about? How should I choose/generate an encryption key for gpg?

Comment: Looks like symmetric gpg derives the key from a passphrase. Is it safe to use the same passphrase for every document I encrypt? Obviously if the passphrase is stolen then everything would be compromised, but is it cryptographically worse to use the same one?

Comment: This goes beyond my knowledge, i'm absolutely not a cryptography expert.

Comment: @Halen: the risk about the use of the same password or passphrase for different files is another and interesting question you might search a good answer here. The core of the question is "Is sharing of secret good or bad to secret?".

Answer (score 1):

Are you set on encrypting **individual files**? Your question doesn't contain a reason why that would be a hard requirement.

If you aren't dead set on that, the Mac has built-in support for **encrypted volumes**. Start the disc utility program and type ⌘N. The volume can be stored in a file on your drive and can optionally be AES encrypted. When you need it, just mount it like you would mount a drive and you can work with the files inside normally.

You can even transmit this encrypted volume securely over insecure channels. The only thing I'm not certain about is whether there's a way to read encrypted volume files on an iPhone.

---

It is generally **not** advisable to write your own software when dealing with cryptography. There's a considerable risk that you'll make some implementation "mistake" that will make it easy to extract a key, run side-channel attacks or otherwise compromise your solution.

"mistake" because many of those aren't really mistakes, but trade-offs - such as the way that is better for performance being less secure.