# IV Reverse AES-256-CBC PKCS#7

Tags: cryptography, aes

I'm a freshmen in cryptography and want to know more about IV reversing. 
There's a lot of posts about finding the passphrase with a new IV. But what about the other situation? This is for educational purposes.

I have a cypher text :

```
cY1Y1VPXbhUqzYLIOVR0RhUXD5l+dmymBfr1vIKlyqD8KqHUUp2I3dhFXgASdGWzRhOdTj8WWFTJ PK0k/GDEVUBDCk1MiB8rCmTZluVHImczlOXEwJSUEgwDHA6AbiCwyAU58e9j9QbN+HwEm1TPKHQ6 JrIOpdFWoYjS+cUCZfo/85Lqi26Gj7JJxCDF8PrBp/EtHLmmTmaAVWS0ID2cJpdmNDl54N7tg5TF TrdtcIplc1tDvoCLFPEomNa5booC
```

The corresponding plain text  :

```
Marvin: "I am at a rough estimate thirty billion times more intelligent than you. Let me give you an example. Think of a number, any number."
Zem: "Er, five."
Marvin: "Wrong. You see?"
```

And the passphrase :

```
AQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMDQ4PEBESExQVFhcYGRqrHB0eHyA=
```

I looked [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase) and [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html) but haven't found what I need.

How can I use those to find the IV? The IV length is unknown.

Comment: Do you mean the key or IV?

Comment: I mean the IV. But if you can got both easily it's ok too !

Comment: Usually the algorithm and mode of operation is known in advance. Was AES / CBC mode used for this encryption (don't let us try all posibilities!)? Note that your passphrase does not seem to be a passphrase, it looks quite a lot like a base 64 encoded key value. Keys are binary, passphrases are text.

Comment: For CBC mode, the IV length is the same as the block length.  Since the block length of AES is always 16 bytes (128 bits) that is your IV length,

Comment: Come on man, for real ?
Asking for other peoples to solve the chall for you ? At least, link the credits ! --" <br><br>
https://www.root-me.org/en/Challenges/Cryptanalysis/Initialisation-Vector Btw, the value given isn't the flag, pfew ! (well, not hardcoded at least...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its AES in CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding.

The IV in CBC is XOR'ed with the plaintext. This results in the following value in hexadecimals:

```
043e1e461f5d6563503050155d7f5b5d
```

and "Marvin: \"I am at" is:

```
4d617276696e3a20224920616d206174
```

so the IV will be the two values XOR'ed:

```
495f6c3076335f4372797074305f3a29
```